# class cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = Localhost; database = venuesdb; user id = root; Password = "

    Dim SQLDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim DatabaseDatSet As New DataTable
    Dim Bindsource As New BindingSource
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand


    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query = "Select * From venuesdb.Event "
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command()
        SQLDataAdapter.Fill(DatabaseDatSet)
        Bindsource.DataSource = DatabaseDatSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Bindsource
        SQLDataAdapter.Update(DatabaseDatSet)
        MySqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
    MySqlConn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

it says "Class 'Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cannot be indexed because it has no default property."

Whats the problem with it??

Comment: It is just typo: `SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command` no parenthesys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the parens on Command.

```
SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command
```

The parens indicate a function call (or indexed property) rather than the assignment you want in this case.

Comment: Question caused by simple typographical errors should only be closed not answered

Comment: There is no indication yet that it was a typo, the user may have been trying to do this intentionally, but incorrectly.

Comment: As for the Bindsource or the DatabaseDatSet ?

Comment: I'm not going to criticize someone over their variable names when those have nothing to do with the problem.  they could easily be abbreviations.

Comment: Even if it was a typo, he is asking "what's wrong".  An explanation of what is wrong, why it's wrong, and how to fix it could help others who are getting the same error message.